# How do you return an integer from a database using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

**Hi everyone. I am selecting a column from a table which returns a field with a number. I wish to return this number to an integer in c# so that I can increment the integer by 1 after getting it. I am using visual studio 2010,C# and oracle as my database**

**This is my code:**
**Hi guys. I tried as you told me but it did not work. It is crashing--+        $exception  {"Unable to cast object of type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader' to type 'System.IConvertible'."}    System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}

**

```
public static int GetRunNumber(string date)
    {
        int result;

        DatabaseAdapter dba = DatabaseAdapter.GetInstance();
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT RUN FROM LOAD_CONTROL " +
                          "WHERE START_DATE = (SELECT MAX(START_DATE) " +
                          "FROM LOAD_CONTROL " +
                          "WHERE LOAD_DATE = to_date('" + date + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy')) " +
                          "AND LOAD_DATE = to_date('" + date + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy') ";

        result = Convert.ToInt32(dba.QueryDatabase(sqlQuery));
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: BTW: don't use sql-queries with string-concatenation of input data (search for SQL-injection)

Comment: Just as usual process of converting to integer, for ex. as already mentioned Convert.ToInt32(...)

Comment: @CKoenig and Incognito--I tried to do as you told me but it gave me the above error as shown in my edited code.thanks

Comment: I changed my answer - this should work

Comment: You have a duplicated entry in your where clause 'LOAD_DATE ='.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your comment suggests that the result will be a OracleDataReader - in this case use

```
var reader = dba.QueryDatabase(sqlQuery);
if(reader.Read())
{
  return reader.GetInt32(0);
}
// else error
throw new Exception("no result found");
```

Comment: CKoenig--I am not understanding what you are telling me exactly. Can you please edit my code to what you are trying to tell me please. Thanks for your patience. Mike

Comment: you can remove the while since it returns the first row and leaves method body anyway.

Comment: sure - why not; @mikespiteri: this is almost a edit of your code - just replace everything from "result = ... " with it (or set result = reader.GetInt32(0); instead of "return reader.GetIn32(0) - but then you have to change the error-handling)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) or [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) methods of `Int32` Structure.

Edit : I found this solution on Oracle's documents. It is a different approach but might work for you.

```
// Connection string for your app
string constr = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=oracle"; 

// Creates new connection object.
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
con.Open();

// Change below with your query.
string cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM EMPINFO";
OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(constr);
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(cmdstr, con);
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// Returns the first column of the first row returned from your query and 
// converts it to Int32. You should replace '0' with the column no you desire.
return reader.GetInt32(0);
```

For more info you can check the [document](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375.pdf) I mentioned.